# Mounting up number of calling move constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++14 and am experimenting a `make_vector` builder for constructing elements of `std::vector` in one line, and in place. For example the usage of the builder will look like:

```
make_vector<AnyStruct>() 
  << AnyStruct(1) 
  << AnyStruct(2) 
  << AnyStruct(3);
```

So I created this simple builder as follow:

```
template <typename T>
class make_vector final
{
public:
  make_vector<T> &operator<<(T &&t)
  {
    std::cerr << "operator<< for T" << std::endl;
    data_.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(t));
    return *this;
  }

  operator std::vector<T> &&()
  {
    std::cerr << "implicitly convert to std::vector<T>" << std::endl;
    return std::move(data_);
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

And then supply the builder with a simple struct:

```
struct Foo
{
  inline static size_t constructCount = 0;
  inline static size_t moveCount = 0;

  explicit Foo(int d) : data(d)
  {
    std::cerr << "Foo(int)" << std::endl;
    ++Foo::constructCount;
  }
  explicit Foo(Foo &&other) : data(other.data)
  {
    std::cerr << "Foo(Foo&&)" << std::endl;
    ++Foo::moveCount;
  }
  explicit Foo(const Foo &other) = delete;

  const int data;

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &self)
  {
    os << "Foo(" << self.data << ")";
    return os;
  }
};
```

Finally, I test my `make_vector` with following code:

```
int main(...) {
  make_vector<Foo>() << Foo(1) << Foo(2) << Foo(3);
}
```

And I'm seeing very strange logs:

```
Foo(int) // 1st Foo(1)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(int) // 2nd Foo(2)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(int) // 3rd Foo(3)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(Foo&&)
```

It looks like the 2nd `<< Foo(2)` is moved twice and 3rd `<< Foo(3)` is moved for 3 times. It's not as I expect that move-ctor should occur once for each `Foo(...)`.

I'm expecting the ideal logs be like this:

```
Foo(int) // 1st Foo(1)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(int) // 2nd Foo(2)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
Foo(int) // 3rd Foo(3)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&&)
```

Why is move-ctor called more than once?

Comment: Dude don't worry. The compiler writers are a lot smarter than you.  Also compile at O2.

Comment: The move constructor is also called when the `std::vector` reallocates its internal array

Comment: And `emplace_back` is not the right tool for the job here - you want `push_back` (which has a `T &&` overload).

Comment: @UnholySheep nailed it. This sort of thing comes up a lot, it's a common misconception that `std::vector` is just a simple array. In reality it's constantly moving stuff around.

Comment: I also log the content inside `Foo(Foo&&)` and found the `std::vector` has a lot going on under the hood:

```
Foo(1)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&& 1)
---
Foo(2)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&& 2)
Foo(Foo&& 1)
---
Foo(3)
operator<< for T
Foo(Foo&& 3)
Foo(Foo&& 1)
Foo(Foo&& 2)
```

Comment: Don't mark move or copy constructors `explicit`. If you do, you don't fulfill the MoveConstructible requirement used everywhere in the standard library, including as a requirement for `std::vector`'s modifiers. Also, always mark move constructors `noexcept` when possible, otherwise you loose exception guarantees on `std::vector`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks a lot!

On "MoveConstructible requirement, can you give me some examples or link for further studying?

Comment: @TCWang See cppreference.com on [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible). If the move constructor is `explicit` the copy-initialization in `T u = rv;` will not consider it. But I made a mistake, the modifiers of vector actually only require [MoveInsertable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveInsertable), which is still satisfied with explicit move constructor. So you are actually good in this case. See e.g. the requirements listed on [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: In any case, it is very unconventional to make a copy/move constructor `explicit` and it will likely only cause you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
data_.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(t));
```

will add elements to the vector. But if the vector runs out of space it will allocate a larger chunk of memory and copy or, if possible, move the existing objects into the new storage.

You need to be much more clever to cache all the objects, reserve enough space for them and only at the end emplace them all.